# Can you use an ENV array of values in a custom configuration Settings.yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, environment-variables, development-environment

I have an array of ENV variables defined as below in my `.env` file:

```
WEBHOOK_SIGNATURES=
  -value_1
  -value_2
  -value_3
```

I also have an `external_service.yml` [custom configuration file](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration) to which I would like to add this array of values so I can access them via `Rails.configuration.x.external_service.webhook_signatures` instead of `ENV["WEBHOOK_SIGNATURES"]`

```
default: &default
  webhook_signatures: <%= ENV['WEBHOOK_SIGNATURES'] %>

production:
  <<: *default

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
```

The problem is that `Rails.configuration.x.external_service.webhook_signatures` is returning `nil`.

Is there a proper way to define an array of values for a custom configuration file?

EDIT: In the end I defined it in the `external_service.yml` file as follow:

```
webhook_signatures: <%= ENV['WEBHOOK_SIGNATURES']&.split(',')&.map(&:strip) %>
```

It works, effectively converting the multiline variable in the .env to an array of values available using `Rails.configuration.x.external_service.webhook_signatures` .

If there's a better, less nasty way I'd appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

The `dotenv` gem does not support YAML format in the `.env` file. You can use `"`s to include newlines within your string if you wanted to, and then you can split on the newline, or just separate your values with `,` or anything else you can rely on not being embedded within your values (then split it as you're already on the path to doing).